# Node.js on Windows: console color output showing escape sequences not colors

Tags: node.js, windows, console, ansi-escape

Node.js by default uses escape sequences to color various kinds of output, such as error messages. On my Windows 10 system, this is in some circumstances not working:

```
C:\t>type a.js
console.log(x)

C:\t>node a.js
C:\t\a.js:1
console.log(x)
            ^

ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\t\a.js:1:13)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

(Most of the above lines begin with a question mark in a square, then open square bracket, then 90m, obviously an escape sequence being rendered literally rather than interpreted.)

It might be tempting to conclude that my Windows console somehow got broken, but color output works for other things, like git and ripgrep, and even Node in repl mode:

```
C:\t>node
Welcome to Node.js v14.16.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> console.trace(99)
Trace: 99
    at REPL7:1:9
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:133:18)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:484:29)
    at bound (domain.js:413:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:424:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:817:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:337:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:666:8)
undefined
```

No literally rendered escape sequences in the above; 99 is colored yellow and undefined is colored dark gray. So the capability does exist at some level; it's just not being activated correctly.

What's going wrong, and what's the best way to fix it?

Comment: Sounds more like your console font isn't capable of displaying unicode. Not sure if this is possible for your task at hand but maybe try running this in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) console (which is a great thing imho anyway).

Comment: @Filburt That's a surprising conclusion; what do you base this on? What do you think the [90m at the start of each line and [39m at the end of each line were supposed to render as?

Comment: Well I guess the *"question mark in a square"* is a dead giveaway for an encoding issue. What does it look like if you pipe the output to a file?

Comment: @Filburt When I pipe stderr to a file, it just comes out as plain text, clearly Node notices the redirection and stops trying to use colors. However – this is really weird – if I pipe stdout to a file (which should do nothing! the error message is not going to stdout in the first place!) then the error message (to stderr, which is just going to the console like normal) comes out correctly formatted with those lines as dark gray.

Comment: If you don't want to install Windows Terminal, maybe try running your commands in Powershell just to see if a different console can handle what Node is producing here. I don't have any clue about Node - I only can tell from comparing running git in the old console vs. Powershell vs. Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Start using `cmder`. It is the ultimate fix. No hectic. Just uncompress it and run.
Download `cmder` from https://cmder.net/